# Paypal payouts from one wallet

Tags: paypal

We implemented PayPal payouts - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/ and we need to make the payout in different currencies.  We would like to have only one wallet (I mean one currency wallet for, example USD).  But we want to make payments in different currencies (for example GBP, EUR, RUR etc).

Right now if we try to make the payout in GBP we got an error.  When we add GBP wallet, add money to them and run the same query, everything works fine.  We don't want to have too many wallets in different currencies.  This makes it difficult, too many currencies to support.

Is it possible to have only one wallet (in one currency) and make payments in different currencies?

What do we need to use? What do we need to set up? etc?